# Create a loop that runs function (with parameters which are indices of data set) on all items of the data set?

Tags: python, numpy

so I've got a function:

```
def connection(n,m,r):
          is_connected = ((x[n]-x[m])**2 + (y[n]-y[m])**2)**0.5
          if is_connected < 2*r:
              return n + " " + "connects with" + " " + m
          else:
              return "no connection"
```

This basically sees whether two circles (with coordinates that correspond to the indices n and m) connect. The n and m parameters refer to the indices in the data sets x and y, which come from a numpy.random array:

```
array([[ 0.31730234,  0.73662906],
   [ 0.54488759,  0.09462212],
   [ 0.07500703,  0.36148366],
   [ 0.33200281,  0.04550565],
   [ 0.3420866 ,  0.9425797 ],
   [ 0.36115391,  0.16670599],
   [ 0.95586938,  0.52599398],
   [ 0.13707665,  0.6574444 ],
   [ 0.77766138,  0.56875582],
   [ 0.79618595,  0.7139309 ]])
```

Since the array is basically 10 sets of coordinates, I have produced two lists out of them, x and y (x is the first column of the array, y is the second). m and n are indices in these lists. Therefore, n and m correspond to indices in the array, but I'm not sure how?

What I've been doing now is manually inputting the indices to see whether any two circles in this array connect - is there a -for loop that can do this in a more efficient way?

Comment: what is the `r` in the function? there are only two values per each item in the array.

Comment: sorry, r is the radius of the disks who's centres are these coordinates. It will be changed throughout the programme, which is why it is also an argument.

Comment: @Amanc if `r` is changed throughout the program independent of the actual coordinates given, it should not be an argument, it should be a member of a class, and the function should be part of the class.

Comment: @InbarRose the idea is that every time I run the for loop and the function, I would be changing the radius and generating different sets of data.

Comment: @Amanc after looking at some of your responses. i must say your question is not clear at all. -- 
you want to have a function that compares two circles to see if there is an overlap -- and to do this you need a list of pairs of circles to match to eachother. that should be your approach.

Comment: @InbarRose sorry about that. The idea is that the centre coordinates of the circles are in the array, so the array I've got has 10 circles in it. I need to try every combination of these circles in my function to see if they connect. Does that make better sense?

Answer (score 4):

You should be doing things differently anyway. Unfortunatly the `cKDTree` which is much faster does not have the necessary features, but even the other `KDTree` should give you a vast speed increase (and solve it much more elegantly)

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
from itertools import chain

tree = KDTree(circles)

# unfortunatly only a list of lists, because there may be a different amount
# also the point itself is included every time.
connections = tree.query_ball_tree(tree, 2*r)

# if all you want is a list of lists of what connects with what
# connections is already what you need. The rest creates a connectivity matrix:    

repeats = [len(l) for l in connections]
x_point = np.arange(len(circles)).repeat(repeats)
y_point = np.fromiter(chain(*connections), dtype=np.intp)

# or construct a sparse matrix here instead, scipy.sparse has some graph tools
# maybe it even has a better thing to do this.
connected = np.zeros((len(circles),) * 2, dtype=bool)
connected[x_point, y_point] = True
```

While it doesn't use `cKDTree` unfortunatly, this still saves you the `O(N^2)` complexity... Of course if `len(circles)` is small, that does not matter, but then you can just use broadcasting, (or also `distance_matrix` from `scipy.spatial`):

```
distances = np.sqrt(((circles[:,None,:] - circles)**2).sum(-1))
connected = distances < (2 * r)

# if you need the list of lists/arrays here you can do:
connections = [np.flatnonzero(c) for c in connected]
```

But note that the second method is a memory hungry monster and only any good if `circles` is small.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm getting this error though:
NameError: name 'x_point' is not defined

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I am still getting a NameError with r being undefined, and therefore x_point and y_point being undefined, and the code not working.

Comment: @Amanc well, `r` is your radius (or maybe `2*r`), its your job to define it.

Comment: very elegant solution, thank you, but its a bit over my head as my python experience is very very limited. am trying to break it down and help myself understand it bit by bit though, so thank you for improving my ability!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Just realized what follows is just an expanded version of seberg's last method...

If your data sets are small, as in (very) few thousands of elements, you can brute force things with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
n = 10 # the number of circles
circles = np.random.rand(n, 2) # the array of centers
distances = circles.reshape(n, 1, 2) - circles.reshape(1, n, 2)
# distances now has shape (n, n, 2)
distances = np.sqrt(np.sum(distances**2, axis=2))
# distances now has shape (n, n)
# distances[i, j] holds the distance between the i-th and j-th circle centers
```

When you want to check which circles of radius `r` overlap, you can do something like this:

```
r = 0.1
overlap = distances < 2 * r
# overlap[i, j] is True if the i-th and j-th circle overlap, False if not
```

These last 2 lines you can reuse for any values of `r` you want, without having to do the more calculation intensive previous step.

It uses a lot of unnecessary memory, so it will break down for (moderately) large data sets, but since all loops are being run under hood by numpy, it should be fast.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward example would be:

```
# m is your array
rows = m.shape[0]
for x in range(rows):
    for y in range(rows)[x+1:]:
        # x, y correspond to indices of two circles
        conn = connection(x, y, r)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem is, however, my parameters aren't the coordinates of the circle. My paramaters are actually two different circles with the same radius, and the other parameter is the radius. So the idea would be for the function to loop over every combination of two circles in the array. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for your help.
I'm getting this error though: 
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use an integer as a list (accessing an element). I see from your code that you are using the names x and y, same as in the code I've posted. Try renaming them, as it looks like they are overriding yours.

Comment: Oh and [Inbar Rose's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14090229/1937129) is a nice pythonic answer :).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

to do so, simply change connection to accept a circle as its parameter, and have the `r` as part of the circle

```
def connection(circle):
    n, m, r = circle
    is_connected = ((x[n]-x[m])**2 + (y[n]-y[m])**2)**0.5
    if is_connected < 2*r:
        return n + " " + "connects with" + " " + m
    else:
        return "no connection"
```

and have your list be a list of circles AND their radius.

```
circles = array([
   [ 0.31730234,  0.73662906, r],
   [ 0.54488759,  0.09462212, r],
   [ 0.07500703,  0.36148366, r],
   [ 0.33200281,  0.04550565, r],
   [ 0.3420866 ,  0.9425797 , r],
   [ 0.36115391,  0.16670599, r],
   [ 0.95586938,  0.52599398, r],
   [ 0.13707665,  0.6574444 , r],
   [ 0.77766138,  0.56875582, r],
   [ 0.79618595,  0.7139309 , r]])
```

then simply do this:

```
map(connection, circles)
```

if the r is external, or a member then you want to use this:

```
def connection(coord):
    n, m = coord
    is_connected = ((x[n]-x[m])**2 + (y[n]-y[m])**2)**0.5
    if is_connected < 2*r:
        return n + " " + "connects with" + " " + m
    else:
        return "no connection"

coords = array([
   [ 0.31730234,  0.73662906],
   [ 0.54488759,  0.09462212],
   [ 0.07500703,  0.36148366],
   [ 0.33200281,  0.04550565],
   [ 0.3420866 ,  0.9425797 ],
   [ 0.36115391,  0.16670599],
   [ 0.95586938,  0.52599398],
   [ 0.13707665,  0.6574444 ],
   [ 0.77766138,  0.56875582],
   [ 0.79618595,  0.7139309 ]])

map(connection, coords)
```

or you can keep your current format, and do a slightly uglier implementation. and i still dont know where you get the `r` from.

```
for item in circles:
    connection(item[0], item[1], r)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! When I try running the code, it gives me an issue with my formatting of the -if segment? In other words, it says I can't add strings and variables? Is that true, or is my interpreter acting up?

Comment: Also, n and m aren't the x and y coordinates in the circle - they are actually indices that correspond to two different circles. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @Amanc without seeing the actual error, stacktrace, i can't tell you the actual problem. but you can never add a string to a non-string.

Comment: I've sorted out that problem, I think. Thanks.

The idea, however, is that the function tells me whether [i]two[/i] circles connect - m and n aren't the x and y coordinates of the circles, they are actually indices that correspond to two different circles within the array.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing some of your responses, I have written you a new answer which changes your code entirely.

```
def check_overlap(circleA, circleB, r):
    # your code.
    # in each circle you have [x-coord, y-coord]

circles = [
    [0.34, 0.74], [0.27, 0.19],
    [0.24. 0.94], [0.64, 1.42]]

for a, b in ((a,b) for a in circles for b in circles):
    if a != b:
        check_overlap(a, b, r)
```

this makes it clear what you are doing in your code, python is all about readability.

note: the last function is the same as using [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) but without importing it.

Comment: Thank you! This looks great. One thing though;
I am using numpy.random to generate the array that I have with the coordinates of the centre, and r is the same for all of the circles. That's why I have an array there. Also, do you mean for the list 'circles' to be the same as 'circle_pairs'?

Comment: @Amanc modified the code. yes, i meant circles. and i modified to have the radius external again. this should be exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your help, really.

It looks really good and easy to follow, but I am getting this error after everything:
 -- 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
 -- 
Not really sure how to fix it?

Comment: @Amanc again, this error is perfectly normal, it means you are trying to get a boolean (True/False) value out of a list/array, which is impossibly, you can use any(list) or all(list) to check if any or all of the list are True. but again - you must tell me the error/stack/code being used, else i can't really help more than this.

Comment: You don't want `itertools.product` or this kind of loop, because that (i) compares points to themselves; (ii) compares different points twice (in each order). You want `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel good point. but i will leave the answer as it is at the moment, i don't have time to fix it myself, feel free if you can.

Comment: @InbarRose this is what i inputted: -- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/annikamonari/<ipython-input-278-e62e9308b1cc> in <module>()
      1 for a, b in ((a,b) for a in disks for b in disks):
----> 2     if a != b:
      3         check_overlap(a,b,0.1)
      4 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() -- Is that the information you need? Thanks.

Comment: @Amanc okay, but what did you put in `check_overlap` what is the function doing now?

Comment: @InbarRose I put in (a,b,0.1).
Also, I found a solution elsewhere for this error message and replaced  (a,b) with logic_and(a,b) in the brackets after -in-, and there was no error message. However, the loop didn't return anything.

Comment: @Amanc i mean what does the function do. copy the function here.

Comment: @Amanc im sorry, i can not help you like this. you have so much code that i can't see. and you are modifying the code that i posted, so i can not know exactly what your program is doing. whatever it is, im sure its not so difficult to understand on your own. good luck.

Comment: @InbarRose thanks for your help. Hopefully I'll manage to figure out something...